# How to discard flags defined in imported third party packages in my application

Tags: go, command-line, flags

Consider, my application uses a third party library. I want my application to accept only the flags defined in my application and not the flags defined in imported packages.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    log "github.com/golang/glog"
)

var myFlag int

func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&myFlag, "my_flag", 0, "need only my flags")
    confDir := "/Users/foo/test/logs" //assume this is read from configuration file
    flag.Set("log_dir", confDir)
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.Errorln("flag", myFlag)
    log.V(0).Infoln("flag", myFlag)
    fmt.Println("test", myFlag)
}
```

In above code sample, log package has many flags. After compiling when I execute following command, all flags including "my_flag" and flags from log package are displayed. But, I want to set the values for log package flags from my code with values obtained from configuration file.

```
  -alsologtostderr
        log to standard error as well as files
  -log_backtrace_at value
        when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace
  -log_dir string
        If non-empty, write log files in this directory
  -logtostderr
        log to standard error instead of files
  -my_flag int
        need only my flags
  -stderrthreshold value
        logs at or above this threshold go to stderr
  -v value
        log level for V logs
  -vmodule value
        comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```

How to restrict my application executable from accepting other flags?

Comment: You cannot. If the imported package declares flags they will be part of your application. Use an other package or patch it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to discard the flags of other packages, then you can use a new flagset instead of the default one.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var myFlag int

func main() {
    f := flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
    f.IntVar(&myFlag, "my_flag", 0, "need only my flags")
    confDir := "/Users/foo/test/logs" //assume this is read from configuration file
    f.Set("log_dir", confDir)
    f.Parse(os.Args[1:])
    fmt.Println("test", myFlag)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`flag` functions that aren't methods use the exported package variable `CommandLine`.  You could use

```
flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
```

to reset the exported package variable `CommandLine` in `flag`.  Here's a runnable example of that:

```
package main

import(
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    flag.Int("u", 1, "We don't want this flag")
    flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
    GoodInt := flag.Int("g", 100, "This is a flag we want!")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*GoodInt)
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ go run program.go -h
Usage of /tmp/.../program:
  -g int
    This is a flag we want! (default 100)
exit status 2
```

If you prefer to avoid modifying the package variable, you can do so by creating a new `FlagSet`, which the answer that got in just before me demonstrates.  In that case, make sure you call only methods on the new `FlagSet`, and avoid the `flag` functions that operate on `CommandLine`.

Comment: If I reassign the CommandLine, I couldn't run any test cases "go test " with any flags like "-v", "-run". So instead of replacing the CommandLine variable, I just defined my own function to display the details of flags and replace flag.Usage with that.